# AngularJS Passing Variable to Directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and am writing my first directive. I've got half the way there but am struggling figuring out how to pass some variables to a directive.

My directive:

```
app.directive('chart', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',    
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {    
            var chart = null;
            var opts = {};
            alert(scope[attrs.chartoptions]);

            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                if (!chart) {
                    chart = $.plot(elem, v, opts);
                    elem.show();
                } else {
                    chart.setData(v);
                    chart.setupGrid();
                    chart.draw();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My controller:

```
function AdListCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope, $compile, $routeParams, AlertboxAPI) {
    //grabing ad stats
        $http.get("/ads/stats/").success(function (data) {
            $scope.exports = data.ads;
            if ($scope.exports > 0) {
                $scope.show_export = true;
            } else {
                $scope.show_export = false;
            }

            //loop over the data
            var chart_data = []
            var chart_data_ticks = []
            for (var i = 0; i < data.recent_ads.length; i++) {
                chart_data.push([0, data.recent_ads[i].ads]);
                chart_data_ticks.push(data.recent_ads[i].start);
            }

            //setup the chart

            $scope.data = [{data: chart_data,lines: {show: true, fill: true}}];
            $scope.chart_options = {xaxis: {ticks: [chart_data_ticks]}};


        });
}
```

My Html:

```
<div class='row-fluid' ng-controller="AdListCtrl">
    <div class='span12' style='height:400px;'>
        <chart ng-model='data' style='width:400px;height:300px;display:none;' chartoptions="chart_options"></chart>
        {[{ chart_options }]}
    </div>
</div>
```

I can access the `$scope.data` in the directive, but I can't seem to access the `$scope.chart_options` data.. It's definelty being set as If I echo it, it displays on the page..

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
For some reason, with this directive, if I move the `alert(scope[attrs.chartoptions]);` to inside the $watch, it first alerts as "undefined", then again as the proper value, otherwise it's always undefined. Could it be related to the jquery flot library I'm using to draw the chart?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Try to create a plunker or fiddle to isolate the problem and share here, so that someone can help

Comment: You should just be able to access `scope.chart_options` directly in the directive since you are not declaring a new scope in the directive.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is here:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
```

The [docs on this method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) are unfortunately not that clear, but the first argument to `$watch`, the watchExpression, needs to be an angular expression *string* or a function.  So in your case, I believe that you need to change it to:

```
scope.$watch("attrs.ngModel", function (v) {
```

If that doesn't work, just post a jsfiddle or jsbin.com with your example.